# Binding WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have launched ASP. net aplication that use WCF service, here some code of WEB.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://somehost.com/GiService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
  contract="RespService.IProcess"/>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Problem that this service bind to absolute URI, but if set relative i have error: This URI should be absolute

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="/GiService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
  contract="RespService.IProcess"/>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: This didn't work, how i say i have response: This URI should be absolute